# Syntax error on token ">", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java

```
import java.util.logging.Logger; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import java.math.*; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import java.util.ArrayList; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import java.util.Comparator; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import java.util.List; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.ChatColor; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.Location; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.command.Command; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.entity.Player; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile; //includes not sure if I am missing one.
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin; //includes not sure if I am missing one.


            //spawning a set number of a entity in MC
    int SpawnAmount = 0;
    else if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("SpawnWave")){
        for(SpawnAmount > 0, SpawnAmount--;;){  // getting the error on this > symbol
        player.getWorld().spawnCreature(location, EntityType.ZOMBIE);
        }
    }
```

there is more to the code But everything else works and is declared. This is for a MC plugin. I am new to coding and all so sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your `for` statement is incorrect. Have a look at the Java tutorial to learn how it is done: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: What the heck with those includes, don't you use an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(SpawnAmount > 0, SpawnAmount--;;)
```

into

```
for(;SpawnAmount > 0; SpawnAmount--)
```

And that's probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a `for` loop looks like this `for(init; condition; increment){...}`.

For you, your loop should be: `for(;SpawnAmount > 0; SpawnAmount--)`

Also, variable names typically begin with a lowercase letter, while class names begin with uppercase.